# Some simple examples to understand various types of Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand various types of stochastic processes through some analogical examples using simple experiments like a coin toss or die roll.

The book of [Hwei Hsu](http://webpages.iust.ac.ir/matashbar/teaching/schaum_probability.pdf) (Chapter-5, Page-162-165, "*Classification of Random Process*") names the following stochastic processes:

1. stationary stochastic process
2. nth order distribution of a stochastic process
3. wide sense stationary stochastic process
4. independent stochastic process
5. stationary independent increment processes
6. Markov process
7. Normal process
8. Ergodic process

Kindly, give me some analogies for these types of stochastic processes.

Comment: You seem to have asked the same question twice, could you remove one of the entries?

Comment: @Xi'an, Sorry!  After doing a merge, and deletion of one, the question was getting "Too Broad"-vote. So, I rolled them back.

Comment: This is still too broad a question.  Also, the previous question (which also asked for examples of all eight kinds of process listed here before it was edited) had details of what the OP understood about random processes, and these details revealed that the OP had some misconceptions. Even the current one, asking for an example of a normal process in terms of dice rolls.....